# Dúvida quanto ao uso do JOIN...

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber se o campo em que eu devo fazer a comparação, só pode ser a que contém a primary key, ou pode ser qualquer campo...

Vou dar um exemplo:

```
 CREATE TABLE tabela1(
    idTabela1 INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idTabela1)
    )Engine InnoDB;


 CREATE TABLE tabela2(
    idTabela2 INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idTabela2)
    FOREIGN KEY(idTabela2) REFERENCES tabela1(idTabela1)
    )Engine InnoDB;


 SELECT * FROM tabela1 AS t1 JOIN tabela2 AS t2 ON t1.nome1 = t2.nome2;
```

Eu posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Olá. Pode usar qualquer campo. Veja este exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5388c/1).

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Tem algo errado, sendo tabela2.idtabela2 autoincrement não há como garantir ela ser FK de outra tabela.